# ComputerID in Qt

Tags: windows, qt

Well, i just need a way to get Windows ComputerID (Hardware based), an ID that doesn't change, or something similar, unchangeable unless you do hardware changes in your PC.

Comment: I'm not aware of Qt providing any such functionality. Perhaps you can do something based on a MAC address?

Comment: @Bart MAC address can be changed without changing hardware.

Comment: @Kazuma Which hardware would you like the ID to be based upon? Processor? Disk? RAM? Network interface? GPU?

Comment: @David: Is the network interface id unchangeable?

Comment: Well i need some sort of CPU recognition (ID) that cant be changed unless you change the hardware.

Comment: @Kazuma We are going round in circles here. Which hardware? There's a lot of different components. Which ones matter to you.

Comment: Wait... Processor ID is different for every processor, right? If it is, then Processor ID. If not... Disk (Which should be different for every disk...)

Comment: there is no processor id I think

Comment: There seems, i think you can get it in C++ (Same as computerID), but no idea about Qt. :/

EDIT: Seems that processorID is not unique on each processor. :/

Comment: There used to be a unique ID in some Pentium CPUs if I remember correctly but they removed that some time later because of the privacy implications. You can however compare CPU features to check if the CPU was replaced, it's very likely that a new CPU has some features added or removed (look up CPUID, only supported on x86 and x86-64).

Answer (score 1):

Qt does not provide such a functionality. All you can do is to calculate such a value from the existing hardware, like the CPU, the installed hard disks and/or the MAC address. None of these approaches provides an fully satisfying solution to your problem.

The use the CPU for a hardware based ID you can use the Assembler command `CPUID`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID, http://www.sandpile.org/ia32/cpuid.htm provide some detailed information.

```
QByteArray CPU_Vendor_Name()
{
    char Vendor[13];

    _asm
    {
        // EAX = 0: Get CPU manufacturer
        XOR EAX, EAX
        CPUID

        MOV EAX, EBX
        MOV Vendor[0], al
        MOV Vendor[1], ah
        SHR EAX, 16
        MOV Vendor[2], al
        MOV Vendor[3], ah

        MOV EAX, EDX
        MOV Vendor[4], al
        MOV Vendor[5], ah
        SHR EAX, 16
        MOV Vendor[6], al
        MOV Vendor[7], ah

        MOV EAX, ECX
        MOV Vendor[8], al
        MOV Vendor[9], ah
        SHR EAX, 16
        MOV Vendor[10], al
        MOV Vendor[11], ah
        MOV Vendor[12], 00
    }
    return QByteArray(Vendor);
}
```

This will return "GenuineIntel" for all intel processors and "AuthenticAMD" for AMD processor. This is quite useless, but with other parameters in the EAX register you get detailed information about the processor (detailed model, features, etc.). You can use this to calculate an ID (for example: `SHA(Vendor, Model, BrandID, CPUCount)`) etc. But bear in mind that the same processor will always result in the same ID.

You can enrich your ID with the MAC address (= `SHA(Vendor, ..., MAC)`), but the MAC address can be changed, although it's not very likely that the average computer will do that frequently.

In case you want to implement some sort of copy protection, remember that every copy protection can be cracked, so you shouldn't punish your users with a very sophisticated protection that limits the use of your software for them.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post, but I came across this document and had to post it because it explains the CPUID and the process of extracting the CPU information from the chip. Not that  @Wolfgang Plaschg was in any way incorrect. As a newb, his answer made some sense but there was a slight level of abstraction that I wasn't seeing through at first. Maybe this can help other newbs too... This is the document from Intel:

http://download.intel.com/design/PentiumIII/applnots/24512501.pdf

if the link fails or is no longer available, search for the Intel AP-909 Application Note. Also, this link is of some help too:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/308483

Enjoy!